# View Ribbon Doesn't work in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-actions

I have been trying to add one view ribbon in my sharepoint list.

For that I `opened the list in sharepoint designer > I go to custom actions > Choose view ribbon.`

Issue what I face is, that the view ribbon doesn't show up.
I want to show the ribbon In every view of my list.

I am using this ribbon to print those items which are selected in list.

After selecting items, user would click print icon in ribbon and JavaScript code in web part would be called.

Can anyone please help me with this?

How to populate a ribbon on list views?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to show the ribbon?

When you create a view ribbon, the view ribbon is displayed under the items ribbon.
[image]

If you want to show the ribbon on the display form, choose display form ribbon.

If you want to show the ribbon on the edit form, choose edit form ribbon.

If you want to show the ribbon on the new form, choose new form ribbon.

[image]

Refer to the following article to create a Custom Action in 2 Steps with SharePoint Designer:

https://www.abelsolutions.com/creating-a-custom-action-in-2-steps-with-sharepoint-designer/

Comment: Hello, I want to make a view ribbon. And I exactly followed the same step. I'm not able to see that. Another thing is, I created Display Form Ribbon and Edit Form Ribbon which both are visible but this is the only one which doesn't show up. :(